# Assign Window Height to Document Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any ideas as to how this is accomplished?

```
$(document).css('height', $(window).height())
```

```
$('body, html').height($(window).height())
alert('$(document).height(): ' + $(document).height() + "\n$('body').height(): " +   $('body').height() + "\n$('html').height(): " + $('html').height() + '\n$(window).height(): ' + $(window).height())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("html,body").css("height", screen.height);​
```

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvmQW/)

Answer (score 1):

To get get screen width and height.

```
alert ("screen W = " + screen.width );
alert ("screen H = " + screen.height );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```